# UIModalPresentationFormSheet on iPad - hide status bar

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad

Any idea why it's not possible to hide status bar when modal controller is presented as UIModalPresentationFormSheet on iPad? 
override preferedStatusBarHidden doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the navigation bar throw the navigational controller. 
For example use:

```
[infoViewNavController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
```

Where **infoViewNavController** is the Navigation Controller that will hold your viewController for Modal Presentation.

Assuming you are calling it like this:

```
 UINavigationController *infoViewNavController =
        [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewControllerToShow];

infoViewNavController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
infoViewNavController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
[infoViewNavController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];

self.navigationController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
self.navigationController .modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[self.navigationController  presentViewController:infoViewNavController animated:YES completion:nil];
```